# phrase structure: "...from A to B"

Tags: grammar, prepositions, syntactic-analysis, prepositional-phrases

In the sentence "S walked from A to B", how does the interpretation of the semantic relationship between the from-PP and the to-PP affect the grammatical structure of the sentence?

On the interpretation that the from-PP is independent of the to-PP, the corresponding grammatical structure is clear: the from-PP and the to-PP are sisters...

But on the interpretation that the from-PP depends in some way on the to-PP (which is provided support by the oddness of separating them - e.g. *to B, S walked from A), what grammatical structure follows?

Can this second interpretation be represented without using X-bar theory?

Comment: This would be better asked on the linguistics site, here:[link](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions)

Comment: I can tell you, though, that the PP "from A to B" is complement of "walked". It indicates source and goal. The goal is the place to which something moves and the source the place from which it moves.

Comment: Better asked on [linguistics.se]